# Docker image/container not updating

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker image, call it dockerimage/test. Every time I update it, I increment a tag, so dockerimage/test:1, dockerimage/test:2 and so on.

When I pull and run the image on my local machine with docker, it works great, and I can see the changes I'm making to the image. However, I also have a VM with docker installed, and when I pull the image on that and run it, it simply **shows the old version of the website** (i.e. it's like the image hasn't updated, even though docker says it has downloaded a newer version).

I'm wondering if I mistagged an image on the VM, i.e. it's running the wrong image, so I tried removing all the images on the VM, creating a fresh image (i.e. dockerimage/test:3), and running that. Again, works fine on my local machine, just shows the old version on my VM.

I tried clearing my browser cache, making edits to files, making a new registry, restarting the machine, it doesn't make a difference.

At this point, I just want to delete everything associated with this image/container, and get a fresh version. But it looks like docker is storing something so I can't.

I know docker is "smart" about how it handles images - it recognizes duplicate images, files etc. but **is there anyway to force a remove of an image, and force a re-download of an image, so it redownloads all the files?**

Comment: you might have forgot to mention this, but to be on the safe side you push the image to docker hub after you create it right ?

Comment: Check if you have misunderstood how the `latest` tag works: [The misunderstood Docker tag: latest](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)

Comment: Are you pushing that image to DockerHub or your local Docker Registry?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - It's on AWS ECR. Yes, it pushed OK, because I can see it in AWS. And when pulled to one machine, it works fine. Just doesn't on another.

Comment: What `docker ps` shows in the VM? There you can see image that is running on your container. Check if it Is the same that you pushed. Also do `docker history <image-id>` in your VM

Comment: @Robert, thanks. ps shows the images are the same, with the same tag. I tried docker history, this just seems show some creation commands? They seem the same on the different machines.

What would be great is a command to force the delete of an image, and another to force a re-download of an image. Removing images just seems to untag, and remove some data when after all are untagged - but nothing ever seems fully deleted.

Comment: @tgogos - thanks, I've tried using the incremental tags (i.e. dockerimage/test:1, dockerimage/test:2 etc.) as well, same issue.

Comment: Nice, have you also checked that you `docker commit` your images properly? Maybe adding some code will help us understand your workflow and spot potential problems

Comment: @tgogos, thanks :) I haven't used `docker commit` before, I'll check that out. I'm not sure what code I can really provide - the main issue is I'm using the same run command on the same image on different systems and getting different results. One works fine, the other seems to not use the latest image, for some reason.

Comment: CAUTION HERE: If you don't care the data that is in your VM (docker volumes, images, containers), you can try to delete everything inside `/var/lib/docker/*` (and `service docker restart`). That will start docker from scratch. Just for troubleshoting.

Comment: @Robert, that is a useful "nuclear option", thanks. I'd prefer to only remove images that are related to this one, though, if possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to this bugg, for a long time I thought the problem was with docker, but it is not!

The problem is your browser! It is keeping a cache of the website so even if you update the docker image, the browser wont update it right away. You will need to wait for like 10 minutes and refresh the browser or try to open a new one.

To prove my point try to update the image by writing hello world in the home page, then open your browser in private mode and you will see the change right away because private mode doesnt keep a cache.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Tried many things but at the end it was the browser cache that was giving me this problem the whole time XD

Answer (score 0):

From the problem described here it seems you aren't creating a new container with the new image.

So just `run` a new container as soon as you upgrade the image. You can always automate this process. I have continuous deployment pipelines (`bitbucket,ansible` or `jenkins,ansible`) doing it for me.

Comment: I am creating a new container each time, based on the new image (and removing the old one beforehand), but I am willing to bet I'm doing some other silly mistake like this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Interesting. What about Image ID do you see it changing for each new tag? seem like you are just re-tagging the older image. If that isn't case we go back to debug the `docker build` operation.

Comment: This might help. clean up docker [link] (http://blog.yohanliyanage.com/2015/05/docker-clean-up-after-yourself/)

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, for the last two builds, the id is the same, because the underlying website code is the same. I made another update to the website, and built again. This image id is different, so the image ids are changing correctly. However, despite building the same image on different machines, the website isn't updating correctly - you can see my main post for more info.

Comment: @AniruddhaJawanjal, thanks! I've tried the 'dangling' images one, doesn't seem to have helped unfortunately.

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, I meant to say "running the same image" not "building the same image", SO won't let me edit that unfortunately...

Comment: @WordName This is super weird. I have couple of sample images on my [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/smqasims/server/) I deleted the old container (v1), pulled the new tag (v2) and it worked for me. How do you share the images?

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, it is super weird! I'm using an AWS ECR repo. I also tried deleting it and using a new one, didn't seem to help.

Comment: @WordName Any luck? I am curious what might be going wrong? Try comparing history of both of the images and I see you do have updated images on the VM?

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, not yet. My latest try was to create a new repo, send the image from the working machine, and pull it to the VM. No luck. I'm sure it was the right image - I removed the other tagged ones.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to pull docker image with "--no-cache".

Comment: Can you do this? There's nothing in the help for docker pull (docker pull --help) for this, but it sounds like what I want.

Comment: @WordName `--no-cache`  is for `docker build` not `docker pull`.

Comment: My apologies. This is for creating build using Dockerfile.

Comment: @AniruddhaJawanjal, no worries! I've tried it with docker build, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: --no-cache does not work with docker pull